# Where to save the Arraylist of Objects using Gson and SharedPreferences so that when back button is pressed the Arraylist's data is intact

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences, gson

In my application I am trying to save an ArrayList using SharedPreference and Gson jar file. The Arraylist has objects of Person class which implements Serializable. I want the ArrayList to retain its data when back button is pressed.I have seen a lot of code on Internet but nothing suits me particularly. I have written part of the code seeing various solutions but I'm unsure of where to use it and my code also needs a bit of correction but I am unable to do it because I do not have much experience in programming.

Here is part of my code:

//Saving the arraylist

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    //String json = gson.toJson(RecipientArray);
    for(Person p:RecipientArray){
        String json = gson.toJson(p);
        editor.putString("RecList", json);
    }

    editor.commit();
```

//Retrieving the values

```
SharedPreferences prefs =    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
    String json = prefs.getString("RecList", "");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Person p = gson.fromJson(json, Person.class);
    RecipientArray.add(p); //RecipientArray is an ArrayList<Person>
```

Here I am not sure of how to get all Person objects saved earlier. Also I am not sure of where to put these pieces of code. Please help me as soon as possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This code have a problem, because your only put one key "RecList" so that you will put last one Person p to SharedPreferences.

```
   SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        //String json = gson.toJson(RecipientArray);
        for(Person p:RecipientArray){
            String json = gson.toJson(p);
            editor.putString("RecList", json);
        }
    editor.commit();
```

maybe you can change your key like "RecList_"+number and also save your array.size

```
   SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        //String json = gson.toJson(RecipientArray);
        for(int i = 0; i < RecipientArray.size(); i++)
            String json = gson.toJson(RecipientArray.get(i));
            editor.putString("RecList_"+i, json);
            editor.putInt("size",i);
        }
    editor.commit();
```

so you can get all string in your SharedPreferences like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs =    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
int size = prefs.getInt("size");
for(int i = 0;i<size;i++) {
    String json = prefs.getString("RecList_"+i, "");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Person p = gson.fromJson(json, Person.class);
    RecipientArray.add(p); //RecipientArray is an ArrayList<Person>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where can put the above piece of code so that when the back button is pressed the ArrayList doesn't loose its data. Will onPause and onResume be right?

Comment: like onResume or onPause is ok

Comment: The Arraylist is not being saved..When the phone sleeps the ArrayList's size becomes zero